# Please wait when I try to add some category

Tags: category

I kind of 'inherited' a **Magento 1.9.3.1** installation. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with it and have a problem:
I can not add a category.
Everything else works OK except this.
While I try to add the category Magento shows Please wait message and that's it.

> This is what it put in Apache logs when I try:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addSingleNotification() on boolean in /var/www/html/app/code/local/Plugincompany/Easymenu/Model/Observer.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Plugincompany/Easymenu/Model/Observer.php(41): Plugincompany_Easymenu_Model_Observer->_addNewMenuItemNotification()
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Plugincompany_Easymenu_Model_Observer->catalogCategorySaveAfter(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1331): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Plugincompany_Easymenu_Model_Observer), 'catalogCategory...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_categor...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_categor...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/cor in /var/www/html/app/code/local/Plugincompany/Easymenu/Model/Observer.php on line 26, referer: https://www.xyzxyzxyz.com/index.php/mysiteadmin/catalog_category/index/key/f15830589560f5f0c1ec46f2214ba30a/
```

Comment: What I have found out is that the problem causes EasyMenu plug-in. When I deactivate it it is possible to make a category. Now. How to make it work?